# Specific XML Parser to csv in Python

Tags: xml, python-3.x, csv, parsing

I want to parse xml-files to a list and then transform this list into a csv file. The format of the xml looks the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <piadocument title="USPTO-Dokument #8,027,927" guid="111126b1-f927-9bd6-9024-d18a79aaa28e">   <meta>
<list name="Inventors">
<listitem>Deeley, Simon;Bristol</listitem>
<listitem>, Stansfield, Anthony;Bristol</listitem>
</list>
<list name="Claims">
<listitem>1. An on-line system for printing ...</listitem>
<listitem>18. An on-line system for printing value bearing ...</listitem>
</list>   
</meta>  
<chapters /> 
</piadocument>
```

I am interested in the list name="Claims" and want to write each listitem in a separate row of my csv file.
I am familiar with parsing xml files, but I dont know how to reach the type of list name.

Edit: I looked again in my collection of xml-files and found out that the list name Claims does not have the attribute listitem solely. Therefore, I can not filter for listitem but need to specify the list name Claims.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: I specified the xml files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself:

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET
import os
from time import time
t0=time()
import pandas 
InputPfad_der_xml_Dateien = "./"

claim = []
kategorie = []

for xml_file in os.listdir(InputPfad_der_xml_Dateien):
        root = ET.parse(InputPfad_der_xml_Dateien + xml_file).getroot()

        list_items = root.findall("meta/list")
        list_items_claims =[]

        for i in list_items:
            if i.get("name") == "Claims":
                list_items_claims.append(i)

        for i in list_items_claims:
            for e in i:
                claim.append(e.text)
                kategorie.append("Prozess")

data = []
data.append(claim)
data.append(kategorie)

a = pandas.DataFrame(data=data)
data1 = pandas.DataFrame.transpose(a)

pandas.DataFrame(data=data1).to_csv("./classified_claims_prozess.csv", sep=';', header=["Claim", "Category"], index = False)

print("\n\nTime: %i seconds." % (time() - t0))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should read the content of your file and then parse it as xml for which I would use:
   `from xml.etree import cElementTree as eT`
2. Then if you're only interested with the  'Claims', you could directly iter over a list of the  by using:
   `list_items = list(xml_parsed.iter('listitems')) # where xml_parsed is your parsed content`
3. If you have the `list_items` you can use `.text` on each element to get its content.

Comment: This does not work because I have more elements that are named listitems (see edited question above)